# XSL: filter where a date in one field is greater/later than a date in another field

Tags: xml, date, xslt

I have an XML file that looks like this - it's a list of users, and for each user there are two dates. It could be the same date in both fields (first user in my sample file), or it could be different dates (second and third user).

I want to filter this file so it only gives me those users that have a lastActivityDate that's greater/later than datePrivilegeGranted

Ths XML-file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="activityvsprivilege2.xsl"?>
<report>
<title>Display Users</title>
<dateCreated>2016-02-23T13:58:56</dateCreated>
<dateFormat>yyyy/mm/dd</dateFormat>
<user>
<userID>0108484181</userID>
<name>
<displayName>Johansson</displayName>
</name>
<lastActivityDate>2005-08-18</lastActivityDate>
<datePrivilegeGranted>2005-08-18</datePrivilegeGranted>
</user>
<user>
<userID>4187101934</userID>
<name>
<displayName>Karlsson</displayName>
</name>
<lastActivityDate>2015-03-17</lastActivityDate>
<datePrivilegeGranted>2013-08-23</datePrivilegeGranted>
</user>
<user>
<userID>20580001535250</userID>
<name>
<displayName>Persson</displayName>
</name>
<lastActivityDate>2012-05-18</lastActivityDate>
<datePrivilegeGranted>2009-08-20</datePrivilegeGranted>
</user>
</report>
```

The first draft of my XSL stylesheet looks like this - I guess I should do something with the for-each-part?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <user>
    <xsl:for-each select="report/user">
    <patronline>
        <userID><xsl:value-of select="userID"/></userID>
        <displayName><xsl:value-of select="name/displayName"/></displayName>
        <lastActivityDate><xsl:value-of select="lastActivityDate"/></lastActivityDate>
        <datePrivilegeGranted><xsl:value-of select="datePrivilegeGranted"/></datePrivilegeGranted>
    </patronline>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </user>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post the expected output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/report">
    <user>
        <xsl:for-each select="user[translate(lastActivityDate, '-', '') > translate(datePrivilegeGranted, '-', '')]">
            <patronline>
                <xsl:copy-of select="userID | name/displayName | lastActivityDate | datePrivilegeGranted"/>
            </patronline>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </user>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```